Can I pass same `rawContent` string to `APNSMessage` and `GCMMessage` object of AWS Pinpoint?
I'm trying to send push notifications using AWS Pinpoint, and using AWS Java SDK for this task.
So from the documantation I could find that we can send custom rawContent strings to APNSMessage and GCMMessage objects that have aps and notification dictionaries respectively.
So my question here is, can I combine these two into one string and pass same string to APNS and GCM Message from which APNS will pick aps and GCM will pick notification dictionary for further processing.
I could find similar thing on the AWS pinpoint console where they take in content for all push providers in one JSON and publish on to APNS if we select APNS in push provider. PFB the JSON used for sending message using Console. I want to implement same using the Java SDK.
{
    "APNSMessage": {
      "aps": {
        "alert": {
          "title": "Your Notification test TITLE",
          "body": "Your Notification BODY",
          "sound": "default" ,
          "content-available": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "GCMMessage": {
      "notification": {
        "title":"Test GCM title",
        "body":"Test GCM body"
      },
      "data": {}
    },
    "ADMMessage": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "BaiduMessage": {
      "title": "",
      "description": ""
    }
  }


